# How to extract a whitespace from a stringstream c++

Tags: c++

So I have a ASCII file that is supposed to begin with 2 characters a 'P' and a '2' nothing preceding and some form of white space after.

The trouble I'm having is testing an error case where there is white space preceding, I'm using a stringstream since the rest of the task requires similar operations and the rest works fine.

The issue I'm having is extracting white that leads, I know by default the extraction operator has the skipws flag set, so I tried turning the noskipws flag on with no success.

Here are a few things I've tried.

The file is ASCII and begins as such

```
// Imagine there is a space before the P
function(stringstream *pstream) {
    char test;
    (*pstream).get(test); //This will put the character P in test
    (*pstream) >> noskipws >> test; //This does the same thing
}
```

Simple question really how do I not ignore the whitespace while extracting using stringstream preferably since there is more i have to do with stream.

Comment: "I tried turning the noskipws flag on with no success" How was it unsuccessful?

Comment: When the file leads with a whitespace, I still get the character P in test and not a whitespace.

Comment: If you use `std::noskipws` that shouldn't happen. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b27713a91e96fd38 The problem *could* be that the first call (`get(test)`) reads the whitespace character into `test` and then the second line (` >> test`) reads `P` into `test` (if there is a single whitespace preceding `P` in the file).

Comment: No I tried both "solutions" separately. I just posted them both.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/66zp Here's a link to the input file I'm having an issue with, I tried the exact example you posted multiple times and my code still output P after the extraction.

Comment: What do you get as output when you print out `test` after the line `(*pstream).get(test)` and for `... >> test`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out the stream originally started as an ifstream, and didn't use the noskipws function so once I set it there, before converting it to a stringstream everything worked.

Comment: What? How can you convert an `fstream` to a `stringstream`? You called `setbuf`? That's crazy. You casted the pointer? That's totally illegal. Use the `std::istream` base class.

Comment: I opened an ifstream from a file then used rdbuf to change it into a stringstream, I didn't cast a pointer I had the original object.    Is there something unsafe or redundant about this?

Comment: That's the safe way, but it's a bit crazy. Yes, there's a redundancy because `ifstream` contains a member buffer object representing the file, which is then ignored after you call `rdbuf`. Until the `ifstream` is destroyed, the file is open but inaccessible.

Comment: If you have an existing `streambuf` and want a stream interface to it, you can use the public constructor, `std::istream s( & buf );`. If you start with an existing `ifstream`, just bind (cast) it to `std::istream &`.